# Anwser people using mysql_* with MySQLi or PDO?

Tags: discussion

I've read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171933/how-should-we-handle-ext-mysql-deprecation-in-php-questions-older-included and I completely agree with having people commenting about it.

But why not lead them the right way by answering the question using the proper method aka `PDO` or `MySQLi` and completely ignoring the `mysql_*` in an attempt to make people take the next step and move into those ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most questions do not encompass the entire scope of an project. A developer may encounter a specific problem on his little corner of a mysql_*-based project and have little or no control over the implementation of another database API. In that case, a mysqli/PDO answer will be completely useless.

There is nothing wrong with adding a note about the benefits of mysqli/PDO to the end of an answer, but we should provide answers to the question that is asked, not the question we *prefer* to be asked.

Comment: Hi George and thank you for voicing a feedback, I am refering myself to novice people, where they usually post their form and code for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139541/how-do-i-check-database-for-a-value-that-already-exists/17140264#17140264 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139837/connecting-to-and-selecting-a-database-in-mysql/17139859#17139859 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129325/simple-php-and-mysql-array-update/17129405#17129405

Comment: So is given a broken answer the right answer ? Since mysql_* is deprecated given those above mentioned the answer they wanted to hear, to me feels as giving them the wrong answer.

Comment: @Prix It is important to note the difference between _deprecated_ and _broken_. The mysql_* functions are not broken if proper care is taken to use them correctly. There are just less useful and more prone to abuse than the newer functionality. mysql_*-based applications can (and will!) continue to function properly for years to come, and we must be prepared to answer questions for people who have no option to make API changes.

Comment: I am sorry I worded it poorly, deprecated can tell a given function may/will cease existing, in that sense wouldn't it be bad not only leaving registers to such but also leading the new generation to keep using it ?

Comment: @Prix No, for the same reason: This code will continue to work on versions of PHP that include the mysql API, and not all developers will have the option to upgrade to the latest and greatest versions where only mysqli and PDO exist. They will need to continue to support mysql_*. Should we begin answering all IE 6-8 questions with answers that pertain only to IE 9/10?

Comment: so are you saying that a user with win7 should go back into using IE6 as well ? Because your example can work just like this, since the novice user would not understand/know it and ended up using the old version.

Comment: @Prix Of course not. I'm not suggesting that we direct people with PDO/mysqli questions to use mysql_*, or (using your analogy) telling IE 9/10 people to use IE 6. I am saying that we should answer the question that is asked.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer the question asked.** If the question is about `mysql_*`, answer using `mysql_*`.

Why `PDO` is better than `mysql_*` is an answer to completely different question. If you feel that the person posting question doesn't know that, you might add that as a comment to the question, but it's still not a part of the answer.

Comment: Then it makes no sense to indicate to them its deprecated once you want to give it full support to it.

Comment: Prix - why not? The OP may be in a situation where they absolutely can't move away from mysql_* (like a huge old spaghetti app). The fact that it's deprecated is  still good info.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I am mainly concerned about novice users that create posts such as the ones mentioned on George's comment. I understand that there are far old users dealing with pass down code, etc, that they need to fix without moving into PDO or MySQLi and I don't condemn them, but we could at least lead the novice users into using PDO/MySQLi.

Comment: @Prix but imagine a user freshly into all this stuff, barely coming to terms with mysql_* as it is. Suddenly presenting them with code that follows entirely different principles isn't likely to help them in their learning process. Giving them what they need *right now* and pointing out that the code they're writing isn't future-proof is often the best thing to do.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't think so, MySQLi is fairly easier than mysql_*

Comment: @Prix well, Esperanto is easier than English... but how would you feel if I started answering you in the former? (Not that I speak it myself)

Comment: @Pekka웃 except MySQLi and mysql_* are both PHP and not a derived language and what changes is mainly the functions so I don't see your point, use some other analogy.